# Datos de conexión a base de datos local en aplicación de escritorio

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Seguramente haya una pregunta de otro usuario para lo mismo, pero no encontré justamente lo que necesito saber, si alguien sabe me puede pasar el link. 
Mi pregunta es saber como o con que trabajar para no tener que poner el usuario y contraseña en el código. Lo que estoy haciendo es una aplicación de Windows Form que se conecta a un Sql Server en una máquina servidor de forma local. Quisiera saber si existe un método o framework que me permita usar una capa de datos, y tener ahí los datos de conexión o algo así. Para no tener los datos de conexión en el código y que cualquiera de compilando la app, pueda conseguir esos datos.

Gracias. 
Saludos

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad.

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta lo mejor que puedes hacer es agregar un **`connectionStrings`** al **`app.config`** de tu aplicacion. Revisate este enlace: [Get connection string from App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6536715) y este otro: [Connection Strings and Configuration Files](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files)

Answer (score 1):

Para no tener valores que pueden cambiar durante la ejecucion debes definir estos en la configuracion, para esto agregas un `App.config`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="keyConnString" connectionString="aqui connection string"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Vas a tener que agregar la referencia a `System.Configuration` para tener la clase `ConfigurationManager`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Accediendo a la key configurada de esta forma

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["keyConnString"].ConnectionString;
```

De esta forma podras cambiar la conexion a la db sin necesidad de recompilar el codigo